# VMware - How to change path to shared folder on ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, mount

I created a shared folder on VMware, it is mounted on my ubuntu virtual machine to /mnt/hgfs/shared-folder.

Instead, I want to mount it to /path/to/my/web/directory/

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the host is present (which is, after setting up the shared folder with VMware), use this command to mount hosts shared folder :

```
vmhgfs-fuse .host:/shared-folder /path/to/my/web/directory/
```

Use this command to unmount the default mountpoint:

```
sudo umount /mnt/hgfs
```

Comment: After mounting the host shared folder to /path/to/my/web/MY_DIRECTORY/ , I lose access to MY_DIRECTORY. I cannot 'cd' into it - it give no such file or directory error. Running 'ls -al' on MY_DIRECTORY, I see a bunch of '?' in the permissions section and the owners section. Any idea what I might be missing ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @user1124236 you can run "sudo umount MY_DIRECTORY" to revert the mounting. step out of MY_DIRECTORY and try again with sudo

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable named `vmhgfs_mnt` in `/etc/init.d/vmware-tools`

```
vmhgfs_mnt="/mnt/hgfs"
```

You can change `/mnt/hgfs` to `/path/to/my/web/directory`.